# Android: How Retrofit/Volley is better than AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-volley, retrofit, retrofit2

I saw many answers for comparison between Volley and Retrofit. But I'm unable to find any answer for **why both came to front**. What were the issues/bugs/problems in AsyncTask or what were the problems in simple HTTP client/server programs.

Comment: http://instructure.github.io/blog/2013/12/09/volley-vs-retrofit/ Check this link and time consumption table also for your query.

Comment: @SamirBhatt Thanks for the link. But I saw that before and not much stuffs are there to make a proper difference. It doesn't make a satisfactory sense for me

Comment: Give some proper explanation before giving any minus vote. Its a pretty bad way which will discourage people.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually Volley and Retrofit are libraries where AsyncTask is a way of threading.

SimpleHttpClient is an implementation to do HTTP requests, But you will have to handle everything manually like parsing the response and so many. It runs on whichever thread you are calling it from. To run it in a separate thread you will have to create an AsyncTask.

But, Volley and Retrofit library was created to make the HTTP request very simple by reducing boilerplate code. Using this you have to write only a few lines of codes to make an HTTP request and the HTTP requests will be pushed to separate thread automatically.

If SimpleHttpClient and AsyncTask are written in 30lines of code, you can achieve the same using Retrofit or volley in within 6 to 8 lines of code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a little confusion. I know that both of these libries are faster, then how reducing code lines will make the performance faster.

Comment: https://blog.mindorks.com/android-smileyrating-how-i-solved-it-9b5ee30f2c34 This is very helpful as well.. thanks for that +1